# How do I replace the last letter of a string element in an array with replace()

Tags: javascript

I've just started coding..I'm a super beginner and have no idea about regex yet so for now I'd rather not use it. This is an exercise I'm trying to solve. The problem is that when a word contains matching characters, the first character gets the lower case, but what I actually want is the last character of the word to become small.

I don't really require a solution for the problem. Instead I'd rather have some insight on what I'm doing wrong and maybe direct me to the right path :)

```js
function alienLanguage(str) {
  let bigWords = str.toUpperCase().split(" ");
  let lastLetterSmall = [];
  bigWords.forEach(words => {
    lastLetterSmall
      .push(words
      .replace(words
      .charAt(words.length -1), words.charAt(words.length -1).toLowerCase())); 
  });
    console.log(lastLetterSmall.join(' '));
}

alienLanguage("My name is John");
alienLanguage("this is an example");
alienLanguage("Hello World");
alienLanguage("HELLO WORLD");
```

Comment: What's the desired output for those examples?

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorrry! I didn't know about that it's the first time I post something here. 
So the desired output would be: "My NAMe Is JOHn", "THIs Is An EXAMPLe", "HELLo WORLd", "HELLo WORLd". Everything works except for the "EXAMPLe" part which actually outputs "eXAMPLE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only really want to work with *indicies* of the string - you don't need to replace anything dynamically other than the last index - `replace` won't work well, since if you pass it a string, it will only replace the *first* matching letter. For example:

```
'foo'.replace('o', 'x')
```

results in `'fxo'`, because the first `o` (and only the first `o`) gets replaced.

For your code, instead of `replace`, just concatenate the two parts of the string together: the part from index 0 to next-to-last index, and the character at the last index with `toLowerCase()` called on it:

```js
function alienLanguage(str) {
  const result = str
    .toUpperCase()
    .split(" ")
    .map(line => line.slice(0, line.length - 1) + line[line.length - 1].toLowerCase())
    .join(' ');
  console.log(result);
}

alienLanguage("My name is John");
alienLanguage("this is an example");
alienLanguage("Hello World");
alienLanguage("HELLO WORLD");
```

Comment: That works! I studied your solution and understood what I did wrong. Thanks to that now I understand a little more about arrays and methods. Thank you!